# fgets() behaves unexpectedly outside of main()

Tags: c, linux, stdio

I'm trying to run fgets() within a function called "a_function()".

```
int a_function(){
    char* str;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen( "./file.txt", "r" );
    if( NULL != fp ){
        fgets( str, 6, fp );
        printf( "%s\n", str );
    }else{
        printf( "cannot find file\n" );
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void){

    a_function();

    return 0;

}
```

However doing so results in a segfault which occurs when the fgets() function is called. Interestingly, I can copy verbatim my code from a_function into my main() function and everything runs fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a_function(){

    return 0;
}

int main(void){

    a_function();
    char* str;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen( "./file.txt", "r" );
    if( NULL != fp ){
        fgets( str, 6, fp );
        printf( "%s\n", str );
    }else{
        printf( "cannot find file\n" );
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

The code is being compiled via:

```
gcc -g -std=c11 test.c -o test
```

What am I missing here?  Is it a problem with my code or with my computer? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hint: Where did you tell `fgets` to store the string it reads?

Comment: `str` needs to be malloced, or made into a normal char []

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char* str;
fgets( str, 6, fp );
```

In both case you are doing above code, here `str` is not initialized, which contains indeterminate value, input into it cause undefined behavior. Both case are incorrect, even it does not crash sometimes.

Try do the following:

```
char str[6];
fgets(str, sizeof str, fp);
```

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to be the problem. I wonder why it worked in main() though?

Comment: @J.Doe It is UB regardless it worked sometimes, it is only by coincident. We should write robust code rather than rely on dangerous behaviors. :)

Comment: @J.Doe: flutter is right: the fact that your code worked at all is a minor miracle. You cannot assign data through an uninitialized pointer. Another option besides fluter's solution is to use `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

`str` is uninitialized, i.e. it doesn't point to valid memory. So the `fgets` results in undefined behavior.

To fix it, change `char* str` to `char str[6];`